# aws lambda nodejs - error when uploading a zip file compressing by GULP

Tags: gulp, aws-lambda

I'm using Gulp to compress a zip file and then upload it to AWS Lambda. The upload zip file is done manually. Only the process of compressing is handled by Gulp.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
var del = require('del');
var install = require('gulp-install');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var awsLambda = require("node-aws-lambda");

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del(['./dist', './dist.zip']);
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('npm', function() {
  return gulp.src('./package.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe(install({production: true}));
});

gulp.task('zip', function() {
  return gulp.src(['dist/**/*', '!dist/package.json'])
    .pipe(zip('dist.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('deploy', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    ['clean'],
    ['js', 'npm'],
    ['zip'],
    callback
  );
});
```

After running the deploy task, a zip folder named dist.zip is created consists of a index.js file and a node_modules folder. The node_modules folder contains only a lodash library.

This is index.js

```
var _ = require('lodash');

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));


    var b = _.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3);
    console.log(b);

    callback(null, event.key1);  // Echo back the first key value
    //callback('Something went wrong');
};
```

After using AWS lambda console to upload the dist.zip folder. There is an error showing that the lodash library cannot be found

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'lodash'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:71)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
  ]
}
```

But in the zip folder, there is a node_modules directory that contains the lodash lib.

```
dist.zip
|---node_modules
    |--- lodash
|---index.js
```

When i zip the node_modules directory and the file index.js manually, it works fine.

Does anyone have idea what wrongs ? Maybe when compressing using Gulp, there is a misconfigured for the lib path ?

Comment: FWIW, I am here seeking an answer to the EXACT same problem. The zip file from gulp-zip is bad somehow. My suspicion is how it stores relative file paths. My local zip tool (WinRar) stores relative file paths by default and if I manually upload it, it runs fine. If I let gulp-zip build the zip file and then use CLI to upload (aws lambda update-function-code --zip-file) then it errors out as you stated. No answer so far, but a different gulp-zip might be what we are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same problem few days back.
Everyone pointed to gulp zip, however it was not problem with gulp zip.

Below worked fine:

```
gulp
    .src(['sourceDir/**'],         {nodir: true, dot: true}  )
    .pipe(zip('target.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
```

That is, note the below, in 2nd param of src, in the above:

```
{nodir: true, dot: true}
```

That is, we have to include dot files for the zip (ex: .config, .abc, etc.)
So, include above in .src of gulp, else all others like copy, zip, etc. will be improper.

Answer (score 1):

The package gulp-zip is massively popular (4.3k downloads per day) and there does not seem to be any Gulp substitute. The problem is definitely with relative paths and how gulp-zip processes them. *Even when using a base path option in the gulp.src function (example below), gulp-zip finds a way to mess it up.*

```
gulp.task("default", ["build-pre-zip"], function () {
  return gulp.src([
  "dist/**/*"
  ], { base: "dist/" })
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(zip("dist.zip"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"));
});
```

**Since there is no good Gulp solution as of 1/4/2017 I suggest a work-around.** I use Gulp to populate the dist folder first, exactly how I need it with the proper node_modules folder. Then it is time to zip the dist folder properly with relative file paths stored. To do that and also update Lambda, I use a batch file (Windows) of command line options to get the job done.  Here is the upload.bat file I created to take the place of the gulp-zip task:

```
start /wait cmd /c "gulp default"
start /wait cmd /c "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 dist\dist.zip dist\*.*
aws lambda update-function-code --zip-file fileb://dist/dist.zip --function-name your-fn-name-here
```

If you use WinRAR you will [find their command line docs here](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/), for WinZip [go here.](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/285/) That .bat file assumes you are using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) which is a godsend; [get it here.](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

If you are wishing this answer pointed you towards a 100% Gulp solution, to that I say, *"You and me both!"*. Good luck.